# Restrict different type of admins to access each other routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, routes

I am working on admin panel and I have different levels of admins. I have a field "admin_type" in the database to represent the level of the admin. The levels are 1,2,3. Now I want to implement some restrictions so that admin level 1 can't access route that is only for admin level 2.

I have searched google a lot and found this blog post helpful http://bjedrocha.com/rails/2015/03/18/role-based-routing-in-rails/
But When I implemented this it is not working and giving hell of errors
This is the route code. I want this route only accessible by admin level 2

```
constraints RouteConstraint.new do
    get 'admins/donation_analysis' => 'admins#donation_analysis'
end
```

This is the constraint class

```
class RouteConstraint
  def matches?(request)
    user = current_user(request)
    ##render plain: user.inspect
    user.present? && user.admin_type?(:2)
  end

  def current_user(request)
    User.find_by_id(request.session[:user_id])
  end
end
```

routes are

```
constraints RouteConstraint.new do
    get 'admins/donation_analysis' => 'admins#donation_analysis'
  end
  #get 'admins/active_account/:token' => 'admins#active_account'
  get 'admins/link_expiry' => 'admins#link_expiry'
  get 'admins/edit_profile' => 'admins#edit_profile'
  post 'admins/update_profile' => 'admins#update_profile'
  match '/admins/create_account', to: 'admins#create_account', via: 'post'
  match '/admins/:id', to: 'admins#destroy', via: 'get' , as: 'admin_destroy'

  resources :admins
```

But it is not working

[image]

Comment: Your problem is with `user.admin_type?(:2)`. Does that work in the console?

Comment: @DanielWestendorf how should I print it in console?

Comment: @DanielWestendorf ??

Comment: is `admin_type?` boolean field?

Comment: @Gabbar no it is int.

Comment: what is exactly name of this column in database `admin_type?` or `admin_type`

Comment: @Gabbar "admin_type"

Comment: okay, lets try the solution, given below, hope it worked for syntax error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class RouteConstraint
  def matches?(request)
    user = current_user(request)
    ##render plain: user.inspect
    user.present? && user.admin_type == "2"
  end

  def current_user(request)
    User.find_by_id(request.session[:user_id])
  end
end
```

Comment: thanks for your guidance, syntax error is resolved but now it is saying
"Couldn't find User with 'id'=donation_analysis"

Comment: oops, i think routes have conflict, if you don't mind , can you share your routes

Comment: match '/admins/:id', to: 'admins#destroy', via: 'get' , as: 'admin_destroy'

  
resources :admins

Comment: okay, so basically you should write your `get 'admins/donation_analysis' => 'admins#donation_analysis'` above this  
`match '/admins/:id', to: 'admins#destroy', via: 'get' , as: 'admin_destroy' resources :admins`

Comment: what you say now?

Comment: No it is now accessing the route which it should not be.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158996/discussion-between-john-and-gabbar).

Comment: here `RouteConstraint` is not working, anyway we can implement this by using `before_action` callback